# powershell execute command and return value

Tags: powershell, command

this is probably an easy answer for you experts but not sure the best command to use. I want to execute the following command from within powershell :

```
stccmd -rh sldcege-mie003 -rs nsccahs_dev -un Administrator -up STC -cb     nsccahs_dev_cb -cmd "status bobRRC_ADT_OUT_FMT"
```

and return the result. 
The code i have so far is :

```
$sCmd = @'
"stccmd -rh sldcege-mie003 -rs nsccahs_dev -un Administrator -up STC -cb
 nsccahs_dev_cb -cmd '\"status bobRRC_ADT_OUT_FMT\"'"
'@

$Result = Invoke-Command  $sCmd | Out-String
```

The error i am getting is :
Invoke-Command : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named par
ameters.
At E:\Andrew\MonitoreGate.ps1:20 char:25
+ $Result = Invoke-Command <<<<   $sCmd | Out-String
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Command], Parameter
   BindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comma
   nds.InvokeCommandCommand

If i use Invoke-Expression, instead i get the following :
Invoke-Expression : Unexpected token 'status' in expression or statement.
At E:\Andrew\MonitoreGate.ps1:20 char:28
+ $Result = Invoke-Expression <<<<  $sCmd | Out-String
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (status:String) [Invoke-Expression]
   , ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.In
   vokeExpressionCommand

Should i be using Invoke-Command or Invoke-Expression or some other way? Is the $sCmd structure correct in regards to quotes?
The program is to run on same machine (not remotely).

Any help greatly appreciated,
Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

neither, instead use:

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'path_to_stccmd.exe' -ArgumentList "-rh sldcege-mie003 -rs nsccahs_dev -un Administrator -up STC -cb     nsccahs_dev_cb -cmd 'status bobRRC_ADT_OUT_FMT'" -nonewwindow
```

if you dont see the output using the above...try this:

```
$exepath = 'path_to_stccmd.exe'

&$exepath arguments
```